# The private_key_file path points to an empty or invalid file. {snowflake connecting using private key }

Tags: amazon-web-services, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, airflow

I have provided private key file path  which is internal bucket path but unable to connect with Snowflake while running DAG from airflow and unable to extract simple select query as connection failed.

Below steps taken:
1)Uploaded RSA key to S3 bucket and received the url

2)Established connection in Managed apache airflow and  later used connection id in DAG but not able to connect with snowflake and got the error as above..